# Concatenate MySQL result (Join?)

Tags: mysql

I have the following **MySQL** tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `person` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `reference` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3;

INSERT INTO `person` (`id`, `reference`, `email`) VALUES
(1, 'PK001',    'paulk@gmail.com');

CREATE TABLE `review` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `review_type` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `review_body` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `person_id` int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3;

INSERT INTO `review` (`id`, `review_type`, `review_body`, `person_id`) VALUES
(1, 'Personality',  'He has a great personality!',  1),
(2, 'Skills',   'He has multiple skills!',  1);
```

If I run the following PHP:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM person, review WHERE person.id = review.person_id;";
$result = $con->query($sql);

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())  {
    echo $row['review_body'];
    echo ' | ';
    echo $row['review_body'];
    echo '<br>';
}
```

My output is:

```
He has multiple skills! | He has multiple skills!
He has a great personality! | He has a great personality!
```

I would prefer to have it like this:

```
He has multiple skills! | He has a great personality!
```

I *imagine* I will have to wrangle my MySQL query but really not sure where to begin to achieve it this. I would really appreciate some guidance.

Comment: `FROM person, review WHERE person.id = review.person_id` is not how a `join` should be written in 2023. `FROM person as p join review as r on p.id = r.person_id`

Comment: You also don't need an `echo` for every PHP line. `echo $row['review_body'] . ' | ' . $row['review_body'] . '<br>';`

Comment: @user3783243 Thank you. Would you be able to add as an Answer. I've tried one answer given so far but unsuccessful sadly : (

Comment: @Stu I'm looking into this but stumbling in the dark. Trying with `SELECT person.id, GROUP_CONCAT(review.review_body SEPARATOR ' ') FROM person INNER JOIN review ON person.id = review.person_id GROUP BY person.id`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it as follows :

```
SELECT p.id, group_concat(r.review_body)
FROM person p
inner join review r on r.person_id = p.id
group by p.id
```

Using `group_concat` to concat data from a group

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/Kp5H8PG5)

Answer (score 1):

you are calling the two tables separately, you need to make an inner join between the two

exemple:

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.column_name = table2.column_name;
```

or

[see this link](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)

Comment: Thank you so much. 
I've updated my SQL to:

`$sql = "SELECT review_body FROM person INNER JOIN review ON person.id = review.person_id";` but it's still the same output :( 

Would you be able to show me based on my example above how to implement?

Answer (score 1):

you should index your shared id in both tables and use foreign keys for better performance.
this approach is based on the Group concat function.

if you want 1 row for all results.

```
SELECT 1,GROUP_CONCAT( review_body SEPARATOR ' | ') as goruped_result 
FROM person
INNER JOIN review
ON review.person_id = person.id;
```

if you want 1 row per person.id

```
SELECT person.id,GROUP_CONCAT( review_body SEPARATOR ' | ') as   
goruped_result 
FROM person
INNER JOIN review
ON review.person_id = person.id
group by person.id
```

Comment: Why is the `1` needed? `SELECT 1,`

Comment: Oh, missed you aren't using `group by`. This is incorrect implementation. The static 1 is going to just add confusion.